# get user selected option var from $_post - php

Tags: php, jquery

```
    <script>
        //this script show / hide lanes depend on user school choice

        $(document).ready(function () {
            toggleFieldsA();
            toggleFieldsB();
            toggleFieldsC();
            toggleFieldsD();
            toggleFieldsE();


            //this will call our toggleFields function every time the selection value of School field changes
            $("#school").change(function () {
                toggleFieldsA();
                toggleFieldsB();
                toggleFieldsC();
                toggleFieldsD();
                toggleFieldsE();
            });

        });

        function toggleFieldsA() {
            if ($("#school").val() == 'School of Economics')
                $("#a").show();
            else
                $("#a").hide();   
        }

        function toggleFieldsB() {
            if ($("#school").val() == 'School of Computer Science')
                $("#b").show();         
            else
                $("#b").hide();
         }

        function toggleFieldsC() {
            if ($("#school").val() == 'School of Behavioral Sciences')
                $("#c").show();
            else
                $("#c").hide(); 
         }

        function toggleFieldsD() {
            if ($("#school").val() == 'School of Government and Politics')
                $("#d").show();
            else
                $("#d").hide();
             }

         function toggleFieldsE() {
            if ($("#school").val() == 'School of Nursing')
                $("#e").show();
            else
                $("#e").hide();   
        }

    </script>

    <!---this part is course registration form using jquery mobile, javascript, html, and php---->

</head>

<body>


    <?php


        if (!empty($_POST)) {

            //getting other details from the order form (later using files - now only demo capabilities)

            $school_name = $_POST[school_name]; 
            echo $school_name;
            $lane_name = $_POST[lane_name]; 
            echo $lane_name;    
            $year = $_POST[year];   
            echo $year;


        } else {
    ?>



        <div id='school_div'>
                <span><label>School</label></span>
                <?php

                    $sql = "SELECT school_name FROM school";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql);

                    echo "<select id='school' name='school_name'>";
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                        echo "<option value='" . $row['school_name'] ."'>" . $row['school_name'] ."</option>";
                    }
                    echo "</select>";
            ?>
            </div>

                            <!---End of School part---->


            <div id='a'>
                <span><label>Lane</label></span>
                <?php

                    $sql = "SELECT lane_name FROM lane WHERE `lane_school_id` = 1 ORDER BY `lane_name` ASC";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql);

                    echo "<select name='lane_name'>";
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                        echo "<option value='" . $row['lane_name'] ."'>" . $row['lane_name'] ."</option>";
                    }
                    echo "</select>";
            ?>
            </div>

            <div id='b'>
                <span><label>Lane</label></span>
                <?php

                    $sql = "SELECT lane_name FROM lane WHERE `lane_school_id` = 2 ORDER BY `lane_name` ASC";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql);

                    echo "<select name='lane_name'>";
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                        echo "<option value='" . $row['lane_name'] ."'>" . $row['lane_name'] ."</option>";
                    }
                    echo "</select>";
            ?>
            </div>

            <div id='c'>
                <span><label>Lane</label></span>
                <?php

                    $sql = "SELECT lane_name FROM lane WHERE `lane_school_id` = 3 ORDER BY `lane_name` ASC";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql);

                    echo "<select name='lane_name'>";
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                        echo "<option value='" . $row['lane_name'] ."'>" . $row['lane_name'] ."</option>";
                    }
                    echo "</select>";
            ?>
            </div>

            <div id='d'>
                <span><label>Lane</label></span>
                <?php

                    $sql = "SELECT lane_name FROM lane WHERE `lane_school_id` = 4 ORDER BY `lane_name` ASC";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql);

                    echo "<select name='lane_name'>";
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                        echo "<option value='" . $row['lane_name'] ."'>" . $row['lane_name'] ."</option>";
                    }
                    echo "</select>";
            ?>
            </div>

            <div id='e'>
                <span><label>Lane</label></span>
                <?php

                    $sql = "SELECT lane_name FROM lane WHERE `lane_school_id` = 5 ORDER BY `lane_name` ASC";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql);

                    echo "<select name='lane_name'>";
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                        echo "<option value='" . $row['lane_name'] ."'>" . $row['lane_name'] ."</option>";
                    }
                    echo "</select>";
            ?>
            </div>

                            <!---End of Lane part---->
```

/*

I am trying to get user selected option from a form but when i try to get the info by using $_post i'am getting the lest option. i am using hide and show to filter the relevant "lanes" base on "school" choice

I'm getting always 'BA in Nursing'

*/

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, you are trying to send the select values to the php script. For this you will need an html form, if you're not interested in A

```
<form method='POST'><!-- PUT THE PHP that creates the select options here!--></form>
```

Also, it's best to use quotes to access the $_POST super global array associative indexes:

```
        $school_name = $_POST['school_name']; 
        $lane_name = $_POST['lane_name']; 
        $year = $_POST['year'];
```

Also, you could try `print_r($_POST)` to see what values you are receiving from the post!

In addition, the `mysql` extension is deprecated. It would be best if you were to switch to `mysqli` or `PDO` instead!